# 12 Nesi'im and 14 days before Pesach - what's read?

Tags: torah-reading, nissan

Some shuls have a custom to read a section corresponding to the gifts each tribal leader gave for the dedication of the *Mishkan* at the beginning of Nissan.

There are 14 days before Pesach, and only 12 tribes. I know that the offering for each tribe is read on 12 of the days. What section is read on the other 2 days? Is anything read?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think something might be read?

Answer (score 2):

In the *sidur Bes Yaakov* (Emden) it indicates that on the first of *Nisan* 7:1–17 is said; then each paragraph on its day through the eleventh; on the twelfth, 7:78–89 is said; and on the thirteenth, 8:1–4. [On the fourteenth, nothing is.]